# Canadian PR - status change due to marriage?

Tags: immigration, canada

I'm originally from the UK, and received permanent resident status in Canada back in 2018. This was through sponsorship of a common law partner.

We recently got married - are there any documents (or websites) that I need to update with my new marital status? CRA has been updated, but anything need to change on the CIC site?

When originally applying for PR, I seem to remember reading that if marital status changes, then I need to inform someone of that status change. But I don't remember if that was only for cases where status changed *during* the application process, or whether something still needs to be changed after PR has already been granted

Comment: For those of us with only passing familiarity with the bureaucracy of Canadian immigration, could you expand _CRA_ and _CIC?_

Comment: Canada revenue agency = CRA and CIC = Citizenship and immigration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement to update the marital status and most other information (e.g. address change) to IRCC once your application is complete and status granted.

Changes or corrections to name, date of birth, citizenship, gender designation require a new [PR *card* application](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/pr-card/who-can-apply.html). Your status is not affected by a new card application, but an IRCC officer will examine your fulfillment of residency obligation when you apply for a new card (and each time you enter Canada).

When you renew your PR card, you should indicate your marital status (and other personal information) at that time.

Your permanent resident status is independent of your marital status, even if you obtained your PR via family sponsorship.